# File upload service using WCF along with jquery(AJAX) and html client

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I would like to know how to upload a file using WCF by making an AJAX call using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some ready-to-use JQuery plugin. For example, [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/)